# Migrating Cypress "within" feature to Playwright

Tags: css-selectors, playwright, playwright-typescript

I'm migrating my tests from cypress to playwright. I have a content on a page that is used in different ways but contains the same elements. I could handle this situation very easily using "within" in Cypress. How can I do this in Playwright?

I am looking for another way than `page.locator('selector').locator('locator2')`

I am trying to find a way like below.

```
        page1
            .pageItem()
            .within(() => {
                itemValidation.validateData();
            });
```

Comment: What's wrong with `page.locator('selector').locator('locator2')`? Please share the page you're working with so there's a concrete example. Thanks.

Comment: Actually nothing is wrong. I have a workaround for the case. It is very useful to run different functions for specific html block in Cypress. I just started to migrate and i have other cases which uses within. If there is another way it would be better to know. That is why i wanted to ask are there any other solution.